# Calling this.setstate to update any state results in the reset of the sorting done on a mdboostrap table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbootstrap

When i call this.setState to update the value of any state, The sorting of mdboostrap datatable resets for some reason. I am calling a function on the OnClickEvent of the datatable like this

```
<MDBDataTableV5 hover striped responsive bordered theadColor='red' theadTextWhite entriesOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50]} entries={10} pagesAmount={4} data={datatable} searchBottom={false} searchTop onClick={event => { this.toggleKnModal(event,"Open") }} />
```

The toggle event definition:

```
toggleKnModal = (data , type) => {
    let rowIndex = -1
    if (type == "Open") {
        let rowInfo = data.nativeEvent.path[1];
        rowIndex = rowInfo.rowIndex;

        if (rowIndex > 0) {
            let value1 = rowInfo.children[0].innerText;
            let value2 = rowInfo.children[1].innerText;
            let value3 = rowInfo.children[6].innerText; //I have changed the names of the variables 
            this.setState({ knValues: { value1: value1 , value2: value2 , value3: value3 , somenumber: 0 } })
        }
    }
    if (rowIndex != 0)
        this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal })
}
```

If I remove the this.setState code then the sorting of the data table is unchanged.
I tried replacing this.setstate with simply this.state.* and it only updates KnValues but not modal. I have no idea what the issue is and the output log doesn't say anything.

Edit: Also note that both of these states are not related to the datatable in any way

Comment: What react version are you using? The current version don't use class components. Regarding your question, is the filter of your table stored somewhere? Every time the state is updated, the component re-renders.

Comment: @Mähnenwolf I am using react 18.1.0. The data table row gets the values from the state - lrows (which is not being changed here )  but the sorting of the data table is handled by the MDBDataTableV5.